# Question on subsonic 2.2 generated code

Tags: subsonic

Isn't this incorrect code generation? Shouldn't LoadAndCloseReader be used instead?

```
#region PrimaryKey Methods

public PublicationItemCollection PublicationItemRecords()
{
    return new PublicationItemCollection().Where(PublicationItem.Columns.ItemID, ItemID).Load();
}
```